# MOD_WRITE Apache Tomcat REWRITE CONDITIONS combining request_uri and request_method

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a rewrite condition where I want to allow a specific URL in combination with a specific request method. But I'm trying everything but no luck.

What I want to do in words:
 If my URI is /login AND request method is POST then allow (as in no Substitution.)

What I tried that DOES NOT WORK

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} *\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|txt|ttf|json|woff|ico)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/rest/api).*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/login)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html
```

What I would like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|txt|ttf|json|woff|ico)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/jarvis/api).*$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST (HERE I want to put AND to COMBINE THEM)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/login)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html
```

I have a feeling it's easy I just don't know how.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work. With a workaround. Posting it to maybe help other users.

Using the Chain flag like below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [C]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/login)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
```

So if the request coming in has request method POST than no substitution is being done and it moves to the next rule(chain flag working) with is the request URI xxxx in this case /login and if it matches than no substitution is being done just like required.